# BatteryManager Health values

Tags: java, android, battery

I was wondering about the value that I get from the BatteryManager when I want to have the health. 
I get a "2". What does it mean? Can anyone give me all the values I can get and their meanings?

Here is my code for what I want:

`int health = batteryIntent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_HEALTH, 0);`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Take a look at the documentation on [Battery Manager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/BatteryManager.html).

You'll be able to see what these constant values mean. For example, the value `2` that you get corresponds to `BATTERY_HEALTH_GOOD`. You can check that here: [Link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/BatteryManager.html#BATTERY_HEALTH_GOOD).

In your activity, you can check your integer variable `health` against these values like:

```
if (health == BatteryManager.BATTERY_HEALTH_GOOD) {
    // do something, update a textview, show a Toast
} else if (health == BatteryManager.BATTERY_HEALTH_OVERHEAT) {
    // do something else, show a warning
} else if. . . . // check for however many values or check for all
```

This way, you won't need to consider the actual value(numerical value) that `health` variable holds.

Comment: Thank you, that was what I was searching for :)

Comment: @Phil no problem at all.