# BatteryManager Health values "9"

Tags: android, batterymanager

I get a "9" value from `BatteryManager`. What does it mean? Can anyone know this?

Here is my code for what I want:

```
int health = batteryIntent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_HEALTH, 0);
```

Research area.

[BatteryManager Health values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17762243/batterymanager-health-values)

[BatteryStats.Java](http://androidxref.com/9.0.0_r3/xref/frameworks/base/core/java/android/os/BatteryStats.java#256)

[BatteryManager.java](http://androidxref.com/9.0.0_r3/xref/frameworks/base/core/java/android/os/BatteryManager.java)

As per [documentation](http://androidxref.com/9.0.0_r3/xref/frameworks/native/include/batteryservice/BatteryServiceConstants.h) android use below constant.

```
enum {
    BATTERY_STATUS_UNKNOWN = 1,
    BATTERY_STATUS_CHARGING = 2,
    BATTERY_STATUS_DISCHARGING = 3,
    BATTERY_STATUS_NOT_CHARGING = 4,
    BATTERY_STATUS_FULL = 5,
};

enum {
    BATTERY_HEALTH_UNKNOWN = 1,
    BATTERY_HEALTH_GOOD = 2,
    BATTERY_HEALTH_OVERHEAT = 3,
    BATTERY_HEALTH_DEAD = 4,
    BATTERY_HEALTH_OVER_VOLTAGE = 5,
    BATTERY_HEALTH_UNSPECIFIED_FAILURE = 6,
    BATTERY_HEALTH_COLD = 7,
};
```

> > As per my research I did not see anywhere "9" value. This value not come always, rarely come, but I am not able to detect the case.